# There is a bug in the post edit confirmation process - “You have started editing this post. Abandon this edit?”

Tags: bug, status-completed

Please be careful when editing posts.

This bug is reported [approximately 16 hours ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415234/475228) on some other sites.

- When you go to save or cancel your edit, the dialog may not respect your choice.
- Worse, the now edited post may also look like you deleted the entire post.
- [Editing a post leads to a weird behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375054/editing-a-post-leads-to-a-weird-behavior)

> No matter which option you pick in the message box, the edit will go through. Then you won't see the post at all after edits, just white space with votes next to it. Then refresh the page and it works.

Please refresh the page and inspect your work or flag for moderator assistance if a post needs to be rolled back and locked until this bug in the code can be corrected.

Comment: Seems to work again now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regression [is fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415252/475228).

[image]